# Printing out for loop upon user input

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm having issues with displaying my for loop on my page. There is a button which upon the click prompts the user to enter a number then display the iterations of said number through a for loop. I've looked at similar questions that have been asked on here but seem to still be running into a problem.

```
<!doctype hmtl>  
<html>
<head></head>

<button onclick="getNumber()">Click!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function getNumber() {
    var i;
    var num;
    var n = prompt("Please enter a number");
    for(i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        num += n[i];

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += num + " ";  
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: `<!doctype hmtl>` needs to be: `<!doctype html>` and you don't have an opening `<body>` tag. This isn't why your code isn't working, but it makes your HTML invalid.

Comment: I noticed the <body> tag earlier and didn't realize the misspelling on "html" appreciate the heads up @Scott Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to get the `length` property of the users inputted value instead of the value directly.

Also, there are several unnecessary bits in your code and several bad practices that adversely affect performance.

```js
// Get a reference to the HTML (DOM - Document Object Model) elements that 
// you will need access to at this level of scope
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// Don't set up event handling code in the HTML (a.k.a. inline event handling) as it
// makes the HTML harder to read (two languages on a single line), it doesn't follow
// the standard for event handling, and it causes anonymous Global JavaScript functions
// to be made as wrappers around the HTML attribute values. Instead, do it in JavaScript
// like this:
btn.addEventListener("click", getNumber);

function getNumber() {
  // Just scan for the element once, not each time the loop iterates
  var el = document.getElementById("demo");

  // Get the user's input and convert it to a number
  var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"), 10);
  
  // Set up a string that will become the output.
  var output = "";
   
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){  
    // NEVER alter an HTML (DOM) element within a loop as performance suffers
    // because the browser must recreate the entire DOM structure.
    // Instead, set up a variable that holds the results
    output += " " + i;
  }

  // Once loop is done, update element with the variable. But, this way,
  // you are doing it just once, instead of each time the loop iterates.
  // Also, if the new content does not include HTML, then use textContent
  // instead of innerHTML as it lets the browser know that the data does
  // not have to be parsed, which results in a quicker update.
  el.textContent = output;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `< n` is implicitly converting `n` to a number (or at least using its value as number)!

Comment: It is. But, for completeness, I am doing it explicitly as this user seems to be very new to JavaScript.

Comment: Agree it's safer that way!

Comment: Yes, very new to JavaScript and why is there a "10" in the "n" variable?

Comment: @LeopoldStoich That's not in the `n` variable, it's the second argument being passed to the `parseInt()` function that I am using. It tells the JavaScript engine to use base 10 numerals when doing the conversion. If you don't add this and the result of the `prompt` starts with `0`, then the base 8 numeral system is assumed and if the result starts with `0x`, then base 16 is assumed. Since both of those are unusual, it is a best-practice to always pass the `10` as the second argument, to be safe.

Comment: @LeopoldStoich You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote all the answers that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `i < n` not `i < n.length`. Because what you are doing is looping as much times as there is characters in your variable `n` (which is a string by the way). So if the user types `9` only one number is printed because `"9".length` is 1 and there is only one iteration between 0 and 1 (excluded). Try this:

```
function getNumber() {
    var num = 0; // this should be initialized
    var n = prompt("Please enter a number");
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        num += i; // add i
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += num + " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `num` is not even needed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I understood that he wants the sum up untill the number given, so `num` is needed!

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure what exactly you are trying, but if you want repeat for loop till the user entered input, you can do it as following

check this snippet

```js
function getNumber() {
  var i;
  var num;
  var n = prompt("Please enter a number");

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + " ";
  }



}
```

```html
<button onclick="getNumber()">Click!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in `n.length` part. Imagine user provides number "10". The length property for number 10 is 2 so the code inside the loop is executed 2 times instead of 10 times.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<button onclick="getNumber()">Click!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function getNumber() {
    var i;
    var num;
    var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"));
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " " + i;


    }



}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't link to external sites for solutions unless there is a reason why that code can't work here. Even if you do post to an external site, you should also post the code here so that in case the external link becomes invalid in the future, your answer won't.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! I'll remember that for the future!